# Android studio invalid folder structure

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason I am getting a runtime error while loading fonts from assets. I have read couple of questions here saying that assets folder needs to be placed in `src/main/`.

I found out, I have no `main` folder in my folder structure and when I tried to put it just to the `src` folder I am having the same issue.

Any idea why I have no `main`, and in general I seem to have strange folder structure? It might be that I am having parse.com skeleton application. How to fix it?

The way I am trying to access to the font file:

```
  Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "assets/charming_font.ttf");
```

I have checked [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

And this is my folder structure:

[image: My folder structure]

My `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'gson-2.3.1.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']

        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Android project view:

[image]

Comment: you have the old file structure, look into your `build.gradle` file it'll show you how you are referencing your folders.

Comment: Could you please take a look to my edit? I have also tried adding this to sourceSets :  `assets.srcDirs = ['assets']` but it didn't help.

Comment: I think you should change the view to "Android project view" then there should show the "main" under "src"

Comment: which version of Android Studio/Gralde are you using ?

Comment: Android studio version 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also tried adding this to sourceSets : assets.srcDirs = ['assets'] but it didn't help.

That is the right answer, but then `assets/` would be a *peer* of `java/`, not a subdirectory of it.

Comment: Does that mean I should replace `assets/charming_font.ttf` with just `charming_font.ttf`? Because that doesn't work. :/

Comment: @OndrejTokar: No, it means that you should *move* the `assets/` folder to be a peer of `java/` and `res/`, as an immediate subdirectory of your project root directory.

Comment: That worked, plus I had to change path to the ttf as in my first comment. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: dammit I was waiting for the question edit, ninja'd in there! :)